# How can I stop my CD drive ejecting?

Tags: 11.10, cd-drive, eject

When I was using Ubuntu 10.04 I used the command `eject -i 1` to prevent the CD drawer being opened when the button was pressed.  Now I have upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 this command no longer works.   It gives the same output as it did under 10.04:

```
colin@ubuntu-11-10:~$ eject -i 1
CD-Drive may NOT be ejected with device button
```

but the CD drawer opens anyway when you press the button.

Is there a way I can fix this command or another way to stop the drawer opening?

Comment: The reason I like to stop the drawer opening is because I have small children playing in the room, and they like to press buttons.  They've already broken two CD drives by snapping the tray off.  I've also disconnected the reboot button for the same reason.

Comment: I understand you ;-) I use this for lock my laptop's cd-rom

Comment: is My answer enough forma you?

Answer (score 1):

It seems a **bug**. I confirm this, eject lock doesn't works yet.
Add your info to this and contribute:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eject/+bug/885051